# django filter across multiple model fields using predefined choices

Tags: python, django, filter, model

I am trying to filter through a model with the choices defined before the filter.

```
store_choices  = (
    ('harveynichols', 'Harvey Nichols'),
    ('houseoffraser', 'House of Fraser'),
    ('selfridges', 'Selfridges'),
    ('lookfantastic', 'LOOKFANTASTIC'),
    ('superdrug', 'Superdrug'),
    ('boots', 'Boots'),
    ('allbeauty', 'allbeauty'),
    ('asos', 'asos'),
)
 
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    store = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=store_choices)
    brand = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=brand_choices)
    price = django_filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['store', 'brand', 'price']
 

    def store_checks(self, queryset, name, store_choices):
        return Product.objects.filter(
            Q(store__icontains=store_choices) | Q(storehn__icontains=store_choices) | Q(storehof__icontains=store_choices) | Q(
                storesf__icontains=store_choices)
            | Q(storelf__icontains=store_choices) | Q(storesd__icontains=store_choices) | Q(storeboots__icontains=store_choices)
            | Q(storeab__icontains=store_choices) | Q(storea__icontains=store_choices)
        )
```

My Product model, with many fields is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True,null=True,blank=True)
    store = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    brand = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    hyperlink = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    finalimagelink = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    storehn = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storehof = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storesf = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storelf = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storesd = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storeboots = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storeab = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    storea = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

This does not work and returns no products, I am not sure what variable to use instead of `store_choices` with the `Q(XXX__icontains = )`. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post your Product model here, please?

Comment: I have added the model in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the method `store_checks` wasn't used. This should use your method correctly:

```py
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    store = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=store_choices, method='store_checks')
```

And better use `queryset` instead of creating a new one:

```py
    def store_checks(self, queryset, name, store_choices):
        return queryset.filter(
```